# Glassfish Open Message Queue Dead Message resend issue

Tags: glassfish, queue, message

Hope someone can help here; I can't be the only one who has had this issue with Glassfish Open Message Queue :)

In short, when a message ends up in the mq.sys.dmq (The default dead message queue for Open MQ), whether the message is then deleted, resolved or simply left in the dead message queue, on restarting the server - domain1 in my case - the message ends back up in the original destination queue. This only happens once. The next time round it disappears. At times I basically have 2 messages, one in the dead message queue - the original - and a new clone back in the original destination queue.

Could someone please tell me if I'm missing something blindingly obvious, like a something I should be setting on the message on being sent from my client?

Thanks in advance.